# $wpdb->get_row not return records. Query is correct

Tags: php, wordpress

I write function for WordPress which agree or deny dotpay transaction, and I have big problem. When I try call sql query using wpdb->get_row I cant get any result (size is 0). I tried print my query and call in phpMyAdmin - that works.

The query and calling :

```
 $query = "SELECT wp_posts.id "
         ." FROM wp_posts "
         ."INNER JOIN wp_postmeta "
         .   "ON wp_posts.id =  wp_postmeta.post_id " 
         ."WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_value =%d AND wp_postmeta.meta_key='amount' AND post_title = %s;";
$post_id = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare($query, $amount, $description));
```

parameters:

```
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$description = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['description']));
```

I was trying without prepare too, it dosent work.

I cant find any log because this script is calling by dotpay. So wp_config and debug on not work (i supose)

Comment: And does a simple `$wpdb->query( $query );` return `0` rows too?

Comment: I think you should first run the query without the **prepare**. If nothing returns, maybe it doesn't "exist", I mean, maybe the parameters aren't matching indeed.

Comment: I will check, but simple query for size <code> $wpdb ->get_row("SELECT * FROM wp_posts"</code> return correct answer.

Comment: Also, use `$wpdb->posts`, `$wpdb->postmeta` to refer to the tables. We can change the prefix to anything, nothing guarantees it will be `wp_` (as a matter of fact, **it is recommended** that we use something else than the default).

Comment: @SidGBF As i said, when i copy printed query (I write this to file before) everything is ok. Prameters exist.

Comment: @MackieeE it's not work too.

Comment: @brasofilo Sory, not working

Comment: Your query and statement is 100% correct, you should check your $description. It may possible that it has special character.

Comment: Once of tested descripion contained special char, but now i try another without special char and doesnt work to. BTW how to resolve special char?

Comment: Any ideal to show possible error log? I tried call this query without param - using correct var for 'amount' and 'description', work. So problem is in parameters.

Comment: @Ram Sharma  You was right, do you know how to send special char?

Answer (score 0):

Are you having a variable `$wpdb` set as global in your scope?

Answer (score 0):

You can use reg exp below to remove special character but it would be better if you share some of the special characters of your query so that I can give you the better idea.

```
$description = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', $description);
```

if you have special characters in title of post than you need to convert your $description value to match those title and you may need to use htmlentites function of php.